# Spring ROO like Console Application

Tags: java, console, spring-roo

I am looking to build a console driven application, which would somewhat like look like the Spring ROO Console, any ideas ?.

Comment: Any idea about what? How to read and write text from a console?

Comment: as Don said, idea about what.?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [Spring Roo](http://www.springsource.org/roo) shell is based on [JLine](http://jline.sourceforge.net/), but contains a large number of design elements oriented around usability that are not present in JLine. You can read the [shell philosophy](http://static.springsource.org/spring-roo/reference/html/usage.html#usage-shell) section of the Roo reference guide for a brief treatment of some of these enhancements. We've also integrated JANSI to provide a colour shell for Windows users.

We intend to split out the shell from Spring Roo in due course and create a separate project called "Spring Shell". The timeframe for this work has not been finalised, though. In the meantime if you checkout Roo from SVN you'll be able to get use the shell with minimal dependencies and Roo-specific conventions. Using the @Cli* annotations to setup shell commands is also very easy, and you can see examples of this in the remainder of the Roo source code.

Answer (score 0):

I have spiked a couple of bespoke shells based on the spring ROO code in SVN.

I tried hooking or rather (hacking) it in at both the shell level and also using the addon more appropriate mechanism. Possibly OSGi will come later to the official Spring Shell?

ps the roo/shell rocks as a platform for building tool/software.

great work